# jest. testing async functions that do POST and fetch within one function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, jestjs

I need to use jest to test a function that has two functions within it.  The first function within the function I'm trying to test sends a POST to a route that has an API call within it and the second function fetches the data returned from the API from an endpoint on the server I set up.  I know very little about jest and what parts of jest to use to test this function.  Do I nest two tests within one test for the main function?  These are the functions I need to test:

handleSubmit (the main function I need to test):

```
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(event) {
    //event.preventDefault()

    // check what text was put into the form field
    let url = document.getElementById('URL').value
    postURL('/postURL', url)
    .then(updateUI())
    .then(checkURL)

};
```

postURL (the first function nested within the main function that makes the POST)

```
let postURL = async(url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( { data} ),
    });
    try {
        updateUI()
    }catch(error){
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}
```

updateUI (the second function that fetches the data):

```
const updateUI = async () =>{
    const res = await fetch('/sentiment');
    console.log(res);
    try {
        console.log(res.data)
        const allData = await res.json();
        console.log(allData)
        document.getElementById("polarity").innerHTML = allData.polarity;
        document.getElementById("polarityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.polarity_confidence;
        document.getElementById("subjectivity").innerHTML = allData.polarity;
        document.getElementById("subjectivityConfidence").innerHTML = allData.polarity_confidence;
        return allData;
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```